# What are the perldoc perlxxx options?

Tags: perl, perldoc

It appears that using perldoc perl gives the list of, e.g. perlre, perlvar, etc.

Is this the best place to find the list of what's available as an overview or tutorial or reference manual section? Is there another, better list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
perldoc perltoc
```

is a bit more verbose about the various documentation files. If you want a list of core modules, try

```
perldoc perlmodlib
```

Answer (score 1):

See also [best online source to learn perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70573/best-online-source-to-learn-perl)

Specifically for perldoc, you can also view the content online which might be easier on the eyes: [perldoc online](http://perldoc.perl.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I think "perldoc perltoc" is too verbose for just finding the list of "perlxxx" subjects. Instead use "perldoc perl". Or http://perldoc.perl.org/perl.html, which is the online version.

Answer (score 1):

A more friendly starting place, with links to just a select few of the other perlxxx pages, is [perldoc perlintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html).

Answer (score 0):

That should be a good start.  You can also find the same information online: http://perldoc.perl.org/perl.html.

I'm not sure what you mean by better.  There's a ton of good information at http://www.perl.com/ as well.