# Modifying hash within a hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

What is the shortest amount of code to modify a hash within a hash in the following instances:

```
%hash{'a'} = { 1 => one, 
               2 => two };
```

(1) Add a new key to the inner hash of 'a' (ex: c => 4 in the inner hash of 'a')
(2) Changing a value in the inner hash (ex: change the value of 1 to 'ONE')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question, you seem new to perl, so you should look at [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) among others.

Your `%hash` keys contain scalar values that are hashrefs. You can dereference using the `->` operator, eg, `$hashref = {foo=>42}; $hashref->{foo}`. Similarly you can do the same with the values in the hash: `$hash{a}->{1}`. When you chain the indexes, though, there's some syntactic sugar for an implicit `->` between them, so you can just do `$hash{a}{1} = 'ONE'` and so on.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70573/whats-the-best-online-source-to-learn-perl) probably also will give you some useful leads.

Answer (score 1):

```
$hash{a}{c} = 4;

$hash{a}{1} = "ONE";
```